# Picture environment in latex. How can I use the same length but

Tags: diagrams, scaling

I am using the picture environment and this comes from a pdf I found online about it

> The picture environment has one mandatory argument, which specifies
>   the size of the picture. The environment produces a rectangular box
>   with width and height determined by this argument’s two values. The
>   picture environment also has an optional position argument, following
>   the size argument, that can change the origin. (Unlike ordinary
>   optional arguments, this argument is not contained in square
>   brackets.) The optional argument gives the coordinates of the point at
>   the lower-left corner of the picture (thereby determining the origin).
>   For example, if `\unitlength` has been set to 1mm, the command
>   `\begin{picture}(100,200)(10,20)` produces a picture of width 100
>   millimeters and height 200 millimeters, whose lower-left corner is the
>   point (10,20) and whose upper-right corner is therefore the point
>   (110,220).

Is there any way I could use the same length (e.g. 100mm) but with numbers from -3 to 3?So I want the start to be (-3,0) and the end (3,200) So some sort of scaling  on the x-axis perhaps?

Comment: Do you have to have unequal scaling in x and y directions? it is trivial to go from `(-3,0)` to `(3,6)` if `\unitlength=100mm/6` but having unequal scaling would require redefining large parts of picture mode internals.

Answer (score 2):

```
\setlength\unitlength{16.666666mm}
\begin{picture}(6,6)(-3,0)
```

should do what you ask.